# Should I use ReaderT with StateT or just the StateT monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have a following data type:

```
data CheckState = CheckState { envs :: [Env]
                             , curPos :: SrcSpan
                             , inLoop :: Bool
                             , sourceCode :: Text
                             }
```

Now this data type is used within StateT monad:

```
func :: (MonadState CheckState m, MonadError Text m) => m a
```

But two of its records can be placed in ReaderT monad:

```
data CheckState = CheckState { envs :: [Env]
                             , curPos :: SrcSpan
                             }

data CheckContext = CheckContext { inLoop :: Bool
                                 , sourceCode :: Text
                                 }

func :: (MonadReader CheckContext m, MonadState CheckState m, MonadError Text m) 
     => m a
```

which way should i use, the first or the second one?

Comment: This is possibly a matter of opinion (in which case it's off topic for Stack Overflow), but to me the second way makes more sense if you are certain that part of your state will be read only. Note that there is already a RWST monad transformer which combines Reader, Writer and State in one (you don't use Writer here but can easily ignore that part).